# Can I make a background data fetch in an external library?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently making a SDK that would require fetching data in the background. For an example, let's say that the SDK provides some weather data that needs to be relatively fresh to be useful. At some point, the data is outdated and needs to be refreshed. The problem is, that the app might be often used in places with poor internet connection, or with no internet access at all. This brings me to the idea that maybe I should fetch the data in background, when the internet is accessible.

The SDK is packaged into a XCFramework, and distributed using Swift Package Manager. When I try adding capabilities to my target, Xcodes gives me a screen that states "No matches, Capabilities are not supported for SDK".

Is it even possible to make a background data fetch without the access to app capabilities? Or does this responsibility fall to the client app for my SDK? Sorry if the answer is obvious, I've tried searching online for a direct response to my problem, and wasn't able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SDK/framework can't request such capabilities, but it can contain the code necessary to do all the work. You need to expose a function that the client can call to run this code.

E.g.

Inside your framework

```
public func setupBackgroundDataFetching() {
    // create background task
}
```

Then inside your README, you need to tell users that they have to enable this capability and call:

```
let weatherSDK = WeatherSDK()
weatherSDK.setupBackgroundDataFetching()
```

Inside their AppDelegate. Depending on your use case you may need to have the function take in some parameters, or make a singleton class and have this as a static/class func, etc. But the basic idea is the same, wrap up the code and ask the client to invoke it

**Example:**
Heres the repo of a crash reporting tool I use: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa

You'll notice their README contains installation/usage guide which asks users to run a setup method in their AppDelegate, which takes in a configuration. Based on this configuration, they can setup anything they need once the app starts, such as a background task if needed

Comment: This was the response I was expecting to get :) Thank you for the effort